# Проблемы с автоматическим созданием базы данных

Tags: c#, sql-server

Использую код из https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/307283/how-to-create-a-sql-server-database-programmatically-by-using-ado-net

в результате получился такой метод

```
public static void CreativBace(long id)
    {
        String str;
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");

        str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
            "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
            "FILENAME = '"+Form1.pathBase+"\\"+ id + ".mdf', " +
            "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
            "LOG ON (NAME = "+id+ "_log.ldf," +
            "FILENAME = '"+Form1.PathData+"\\"+ id + ".ldf', " +
            "SIZE = 1MB, " +
            "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
            "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
        //try
        //{
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        //}
        //catch (System.Exception ex)
        //{
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        //}
        //finally
        //{
            if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                myConn.Close();
            }
        //}
    }
```

но выдает ошибку

> Invalid usage of the option _log in the CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement."
>   Как исправить?

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Так вы пытаетесь соединится с `MS Sql Server` или же по тегу к вопросу с `MySQL`?

Comment: я пытаюсь создать локальную базу, возможно я допустил ошибку в теге

Comment: у вас в 5 пункте вашего мануала `Введите в строку подключения значение для используемого SQL Server` - вы это сделали?

Comment: Для начала запомните: MySql и SqlServer - совершенно разные СУБД. Не путайте их! | Вы устанавливали на своём компьютере отдельную версию Sql Server? Наверняка, нет. Стало быть, используется LocalDB, которая устанавливается вместо с Visual Studio. Для неё в строке подключения должно быть `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` вместо `localhost` (именно это имел в виду tym32167).

Comment: Спасибо это помогло, но появилась следующая проблема: > Invalid usage of the option _log in the CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement."

Comment: Кавычек вокруг log не хватает?